# How long does yield keeps its status?

Tags: python, deep-learning, yield

I have a huge dataset and want to partially load this files into my RAM, train and delete. In order to realize this I wrote a function, that yields me some small part of my data. My functions idea is like this simplified example:

```
def loop_between(x,y,yield_size):
    for num in range(x,y):
        array(num%yield_size) = num
        if (num+1) % yield_size == 0: 
              yield array
```

My question is: how and how long does yield keeps its status? For example: I call my function with (x,y) = (0,100) and parallel in same code with (x,y) = (200,300). Will the status of yield reset when I call it with different parameters or does it keep different status for its each call?

Comment: What do you mean by "and parallel in same code with"? Are we talking different processes, threads, coroutines?

Comment: Each call to function gives a separate result. In case of functions with `yield`, the function "returns" a generator. So `gen1 = loop_between(a,b,c)` doesn't get affected by `gen2 = loop_between(x,y,z)`. But separate ` loop_between(a,b,c)` (without saving it) will each time start from beginning.

Comment: @GPhilo in simplest case calling them right after each other. like array1 = loop_between(0,100,10); array2 = loop_between(200,300,10)

Comment: Ok then it's as @h4z3 said. Those are two different objects, entirely independent from each other.

Comment: so, they behave like objects then?

Comment: Yes. Everything in Python is an object. Even functions - check `isinstance(len, object)` or `isinstance(loop_between, object)` (see there's no `()` after the function name). You can also check your result - `isinstance(loop_between(a,b,c), object)` (of course put values for a,b,c)

Answer (score 1):

They're distinct objects so the return values will reflect what was passed to them, i.e. one object call doesn't interfere with the other objects return value.

As for your comment, everything in Python is an object ;)